# Autofill sequence of steps in VBA

Tags: excel, vba

I'm trying to generate a code that will fill cells in a row based on the input of the selected cell. In a nutshell, there's 6 steps and the goal is to type "Step 6" in one cell and have Steps 5-1 generate in the 5 cells to the right, however the code cannot be restricted to a fixed cell and must move relative to the first cell selected. Is this possible? Ive used the week autofill as reference below but am lost.

```
Sub Weekday_Data_Update() 
Dim startRange As Range 
Dim stopRange As Range 
Set startRange = Sheets("Sheet1").Range("A2") 
'Specify the cell until which you want weekdays to be displayed 
Set stopRange = Sheets("Sheet1").Range("A2:A6") startRange.Select 
Selection.AutoFill Destination:=stopRange, Type:=xlFillWeekdays 
End Sub
```

Comment: Use `Selection.Offset` to reference other cells based on the position of `Selection`. You can have all of the Ranges used in the macro be dynamically based on the position of `Selection`. You can also use `Selection.EntireColumn.Cells(x)` or `Selection.EntireRow.Cells(x)` to get "the x'th cell in the same row/column as `Selection`.

Comment: To have a macro execute automatically based on a specific trigger, put it in the `Worksheet_Change`  event, and then put the entire code in an If Statement that looks for your specific triggering event, like `Activecell.Value = "Step 6"` or `Not Intersect(Activecell, WatchedRange) Is Nothing`

Answer (score 0):

Like this (code goes in the worksheet module)

```vb
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    Dim v, i As Long
    If Target.CountLarge > 1 Then Exit Sub 'only tracking single-cell changes
    v = Target.Value
    If IsError(v) Then Exit Sub   'cell has error - exit
    If v = "Step 6" Then
        For i = 5 To 1 Step -1
            Target.Offset(0, 6 - i).Value = "Step " & i
        Next i
    End If
End Sub
```